# How to determine if a reconfigured network adapter is ready to transmit?

Tags: .net, networking, wmi, ip

I have a problem with the following process:

1. My application calls a Windows Service running as Administrator to set the network adapter's IP configuration as required.
2. Since a Windows Service cannot easily signal that it has completed the task, the application watches the network adapter until the required configuration is present (with a timeout).
3. The application connects to the target IP address by TCP.

My problem is there is a delay between when the network adapter is configured (step 2) and when it can be used (step 3.)  If I try to ping or connect via TCP immediately after reconfiguring the adapter, I get the error:

> Destination host cannot be reached.

If I include an arbitrary 5-second delay, it works fine, but this is a terrible solution.  I'm using the [Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394217%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMI class to reconfigure and watch the network adapter.  What can I do to ensure the adapter is ready to transmit without risking a race condition?

Comment: The "destination host cannot be reached" is a result of the route not being present in the routing table. You can monitor the windows routing table for that interface.

Comment: I thought attemtping to connect to an address would cause Windows to populate the route table.  Is that correct?

Comment: The route table is built automatically after the interface finishes coming back up. You just need to monitor it and wait until it's built to start sending out traffic.